# change value when count decreases repeated times besides if statememts

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing this pomodoro clock and when i hit 59 seconds i need to change the gradient of the clock background.

This is the value to be changed, 1.7% on 59sec 3.4% for 58sec so on...

```
$("svg linearGradient stop").attr("offset","50%");
```

I know i can write a if statement  or a switch case

```
    var count = $("#counter2").html();
//target svg on click
  $("svg").click(function(){

  var counter = setInterval(timer,1000);

    function timer(){
      count-=1;//count decreases

      //this code does work and it does change the gradient.

      if(count==59) $("svg linearGradient stop").attr("offset","1.67%");
      //.....
      if(count==30) $("svg linearGradient stop").attr("offset","51%");

      $("#time").text(count);
    });
```

Is there any other way to achieve this without writing an if statement 59 times.

Comment: $("svg linearGradient stop").attr("offset",((60-count)*1.7)+"%");??'

Comment: Wouldn't `$("svg linearGradient stop").attr("offset", (1 - count / 60) * 100 + "%");` work?  You totally should be using math to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `count` to calculate the offset?

```
$("svg linearGradient stop").attr("offset", 100 - (100 / 60 * count) + "%");
```

Comment: That's more like it :)

Comment: yup maths is good, i don't want to do this 60 times no other way besides if statement?

Comment: @Pollux01 There shouldn't be any need for any if statements - replace the if statements you have already with a single instance of the code in the answer.